# URLResourceKey.quarantinePropertiesKey is only available on OS X 10.10 or newer when installing chromedriver

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I am downloading `chromedriver` through a `brew cask install` (see [related issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/26759) ) and when I try to download it I get the following error (pasted full output from command entry):

```
(env) MacBook:project_dir owner$ brew cask install chromedriver
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
dnstwist            grpc                pdns                uftp
firebase-cli        lf                  pdnsrec             wildfly-as
glslviewer          libxlsxwriter       tile38              zabbix

==> Satisfying dependencies
==> Downloading https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.41/chromedriver_ma
######################################################################## 100.0%
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/utils/quarantine.swift:29:30: error: 'quarantinePropertiesKey' is only available on OS X 10.10 or newer
      forKey: URLResourceKey.quarantinePropertiesKey
                             ^
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/utils/quarantine.swift:29:30: note: add 'if #available' version check
      forKey: URLResourceKey.quarantinePropertiesKey
                             ^
Error: Failed to quarantine /Users/user/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/42621d77ecaa889fa8ca73ac4b2a2228e3c1d11f20d84c6898e7645397d00f1d--chromedriver_mac64.zip. Here's the reason:
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/utils/quarantine.swift:29:30: error: 'quarantinePropertiesKey' is only available on OS X 10.10 or newer
      forKey: URLResourceKey.quarantinePropertiesKey
                             ^
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/utils/quarantine.swift:29:30: note: add 'if #available' version check
      forKey: URLResourceKey.quarantinePropertiesKey
```

My current macbook specs are as follows:[image]

Has anyone ran into this issue before? Any help would be appreciated. I am trying to set up a headless chrome driver and failing.

UPDATE_EDIT: I've since moved on from Chrome and had more luck using Firefox headless instead, but this is still no solution to the issue above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## This is due to a current bug in Homebrew, and a fix has been merged

Per issue [#4809](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/4809):

> Hi, PR #4656 appears to break brew cask install on 10.11. I get an error on 10.11, but not on 10.12. As a workaround, re-running with the --no-quarantine flag is successful. I'm not sure why this swift feature isn't available, my OS is up to date.
>
> (snip)
>
> ```
> /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cask/lib/hbc/utils/quarantine.swift:29:30: error: 'quarantinePropertiesKey' is only available on OS X 10.10 or newer
>       forKey: URLResourceKey.quarantinePropertiesKey
> ```
>
> (etc)

*(snip and etc mine)*

This is the same issue you are facing.

There is a PR ([#4796](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/pull/4796)) that addresses this, which has been merged into master as of a day ago (2018-09-06):

> The Gatekeeper API I've written relies on an up-to-date CLT (or Xcode) install, and xattr's -r flag for native recursion. There are cases where Swift is too old or is set to a deployment target earlier than MacOS 10.10, and thus cannot use the URLResourceKey.quarantinePropertiesKey constant. And in the current Mojave beta, xattr does not have Apple's -r extension for doing native filesystem traversal.
>
> This pull request inserts an additional check in the Swift script, the Quarantine.available? function and brew cask doctor, and changes propagate to use xargs for recursion.

I just ran a `brew update` and it tells me I am running `1.7.3` running at commit `5d894`, which was committed today (2018-09-07) and is the latest version of [homebrew-core](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core) at time of writing.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response!

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/51554#issuecomment-418215466

try below.

```
$ brew cask install --no-quarantine chromedriver
```

Comment: Hmmm, still no luck sadly. 
"There are two issues at play here. First, the --no-quarantine flag just tells Homebrew to not execute the quarantine process, it will not (currently) "un-quarantine" the download if it was quarantined previously." 
Since I  ran the brew install before it is still quarantined. I think there must be some kind of cache I can clear hopefully.